# Get data ordered by document Id in Firestore by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Get data ordered by document Id in Firestore by Javascript

In Andorid, I can use the query go to specific documents

```
mQuery = docRef.whereEqualTo("name", name)
                .whereEqualTo("valid",true)
                .orderBy(FieldPath.documentId())
                .startAt(lastDocId)
                .limit(LIMIT);
```

It works, but in Javascript, I try to copy a similar query,
it didn't work.

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
    var goQuery = docRef.where("name", "==", name)
                        .where("valid", "==", true)
                        .orderBy(db.FieldPath.documentId())
                        .startAfter("id0070")
                        .limit(LIMIT);
```

It give a error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentId' of undefined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick

Any idea? Thank you for your help.

Comment: why is one `FieldPath.documentId()` and other is `db.FieldPath.documentId()` ?

Comment: Reply to epascarello: cause FieldPath.documentId() will give error:Uncaught ReferenceError: FieldPath is not defined

Comment: @MikeLin I don't think you get what he means. It's simply why is the first one referred as **db.FieldPath** and the other one is **FieldPath**.

Answer (score 25):

By trial and error, the correct grammar is

```
var goQuery = docRef.where("name", "==", name)
                    .where("valid", "==", true)
                    .orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
                    .startAfter("id0070")
                    .limit(LIMIT);
```

**firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()**

Comment: How would I actually use it in Node.js environment without using Firebase ?
I tried `db.FieldPath.documentId()` but it fails with an error `undefined`

Comment: @aspirinemaga - it's probably a bit late now, but you would use whatever var you are using for the `app`. In my case, it was `app`. :)