# Android Firestore How to use document id as field in various queries

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On this page [Query firestore database for document id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876754/query-firestore-database-for-document-id)

I found this javascript example to use documentId in where clause

```
db.collection('books').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', 'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5').get()
```

what would be the Android equivalent to that? I tried using

```
whereEqualTo(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5');
```

but it didn't work

**Edit**: I don't want to use

```
db.collection('books').document("fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5").get()
```

because I want to learn how to use `documentId` as field so that I can use that in other queries like

```
.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
```

(from [Get data ordered by document Id in Firestore by Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772169/get-data-ordered-by-document-id-in-firestore-by-javascript)) in Android

In short, what is the equivalent of `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()` in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use:

```
db.collection('books').document("fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5").get()
```

An option that you have is to add the document ID as a property of the document and use the following query:

```
db.collection("books").whereEqualTo("documentId", "fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5").get()
```

According to Doug Stevenson's comment, it turns out that:

```
db.collection("books").whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), "fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5").get()
```

Actually works, returning the same result as in case of:

```
db.collection('books').document("fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5").get()
```

Or:

```
db.collection("books").whereEqualTo("documentId", "fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5").get()
```

Now, you should simply attach a listener and you're done.

Comment: This isn't really true.  You can, in fact, use `FieldPath.documentId()` in a query to filter by document ID.  You just can't do it with collection group queries.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yep Doug, you're totally right, I missed that. Just updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @DougStevenson I just tested my query with `FieldPath.documentId()` and it really works, Thanks to both of you experts :)

Answer (score 3):

What you're showing should actually work.  As you can see from the API documentation for [FieldPath.documentId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldPath#documentId()):

> Returns A special sentinel `FieldPath` to refer to the ID of a document. It can be **used in queries to sort or filter by the document ID.**

So you should be able to use it to filter for document ID.  I was able to perform a query like this with no problem.  If it doesn't work for you, then something else is wrong - perhaps the document you asked for doesn't actually exist, or you are providing the wrong collection and ID.

Note that filtering by document ID like this doesn't work for collection group queries.  For that, you do need to add the document ID as a field to filter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of querying the collection for document id, query the document directly

```
db.collection('books').document("fK3ddutEpD2qQqRMXNW5").get()
```

Sometimes we miss the straight forward ones!

Comment: Thanks but I need another way to do this, please see my edit!